# How do you ATTACH another SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, intellij-idea

I have an SQLite connection set up as data source in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. How do you [ATTACH](https://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) a separate SQLite database to the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To persist an attached SQLite database, open the data source "Properties", click the "Options" tab, find the "Connection" section, find the "Startup script:" field, and enter the following:

```sql
ATTACH '/path/to/my/second/sqlite.db' AS db2;
```

Answer (score 4):

Open Data Source properties -> Option tab -> Enable 'Single connection mode'. Close all sessions in 'Services' tool window, open new console for this data source and try something like this

```
attach database 'C:\temp\db1.sqlite' as db1;
```

it will be shown in schemas list as db1.

Comment: This appears to work. It would be nice if there was a way to make it persistent.

Comment: @AllWorkersAreEssential you can add that to startup script for your datasource

Comment: @kassak I'm aware that the field exists under "Options" tab. I have no idea how to use it though. How do you write a startup script in the context of SQLite?

Comment: @AllWorkersAreEssential Sorry, can't get what you mean. Just paste `attach database 'C:\temp\db1.sqlite' as db1;` into that field. Now every time connection is started, DG would perform that, thus attach your DB.

Comment: @kassak Thanks, that's what I was wondering. I didn't know if I had to put a path to a bash script in that field. From what you said it sounds like raw SQL statements are what you put in there.